# Creating look up tables in QGIS that last more than one session?

Tags: qgis, postgis, table

It seems that when I create a Look up Table or **Value Map** for a shapefile or a PostgreSQL table in QGIS it saves it for one session, then when I open it again it had disappears.

Can someone enlighten me to this, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you save the default styles for the layer?

Comment: Why would it have anything to do with the styles, when I am I am looking at the fields of the table.  I am looking to create a standard 'Look up table' or 'combo box'.  Thanks

Comment: The style also saves some of the other properties of a layer. If you name the style file (*.qml) the same as the shapefile the style (and some properties) will be loaded default, when opening the shapefile. You can also save default styles to PostGIS.

Comment: I am using the 'edit Widget Properties', **Value Map** is this not the right location to be putting the new look up table values in?

Comment: Yes the right place and the value map is saved and loaded as default, if you save the style as a default style.